# Ruby on Rails app, running under passenger/nginx, occasionally creates world-writable directories and files under tmp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I have a Rails app which has been running for quite some time; however, occasionally it will decide to create files and directories under its "tmp" directory (particularly "tmp/cache") that are world-writable.

As this is an intranet, our system admins find these and complain.

I can certainly set up a cron job to remove the world-write permission, but I'd prefer to address the problem at the source.

For whatever it's worth, this is running under nginx using the Passenger 5.0.9 gem.

Thanks!

Comment: Which user does nginx run under?  Are there any lines in its config which specify this folder?

Comment: The app runs under a non-privileged user.  It's only specified in the "deploy.rb" script, as a directory to not copy when deploying the application.

Comment: I asked about nginx, not the app.  On my local machine for example, nginx runs as the "root" user, in a group called "www-data" which has root priveleges.  I have occasionally had issues with it setting the folder ownership on directories in RAILS_ROOT/tmp to be owned by the www-data group and this sounds like a similar issue.

Comment: My apologies, I missed that.  The same non-privileged user runs both nginx and the Rails app.  As mentioned below, the umask is 022 for that user.

Comment: And is there anything in the nginx config relating to that tmp folder?

Comment: Nope... it's a very simple configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Does the umask of the app user and the nginix user affect this?

Comment: The umask of the non-privileged user runs both nginx and the Rails app is 022.

Comment: Is the 022 explicitly set in / by a configuration file for the shell under which the server and the app processes are executed? For example, if the user has a login csh where the umask is 022, what do you receive if you run "sh umask"?

Comment: sh umask -> "sh: umask: no such file or directory" :-)  However, if I just run "umask", it says "0022".

Comment: "sh umask" seems to work on red hat 7, but not on red hat 6. However, "sh -c umask" should work. Even then, however, you would probably be inheriting the permissions from the shell you were running in.